# Creating states and zones for non US countries

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I'll like to know if is possible to add states and after create zones for a country like Venezuela. I look all over Magento Admin but didn't find where or if it's possible. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Its possible to do this,

But you need to make script that inset new Items in the table called

```
directory_country_region
example ( adding new state for United Arab Emirates ) ( ISO 2-alpha AE ) City name  Dubai Code DXB 
so the query will be
INSERT INTO directory_country_region (region_id,country_id,code,default_name)
VALUES ('','AE','DXB','Dubai');
```

Inset as many as you want, you will find them everywhere in the checkout/shipping quote etc..

Comment: Thanks I'll try and see if that works also is rare Magento haven't a graphic way to do this :(

Comment: I have done module that you can easily manage that http://www.meabed.net/2013/07/18/add-regions-in-magento-address-regionstatecity-field.html